# java split list into two

Tags: java, list

I have a list:

```
 [132567,Amelia, 123476,Charlie, 123516,Emily, 143456,George, 123466,Harry, 123457,Jack, 125456,Joshua, 132456,Lily, 123456,Oliver]
```

I want to split this list into two so one list is ID and another list is NAMES. The requirement is also that ID[1] must correspond to NAME[1] and so forth.

So, in essence, I want to have two lists like this:

```
id    = [132567, 123476, 123516, 143456, 123466, 123457, 125456, 132456, 123456]
names = [Amelia, Charlie, Emily, George, Harry, Jack, Joshua, Lily, Oliver]
```

How do I do this in the simplest way?
Thanks

Comment: You can get all elements at even index(0, 2, 4...) and put all them in `id array` and elements at odd index(1, 3, 5...) put in `names array`

Comment: [Maybe this can help you](https://ideone.com/CYOTuK) but a simple can also do the job

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the ID always starts with a digit and the names doesn't start with digits, you can try this.

```
String text = "132567, Amelia, 123476, Charlie, 123516, Emily, 143456, George, 123466, Harry, 123457, Jack, 125456, Joshua, 132456, Lily, 123456, Oliver";

ArrayList id = new ArrayList(), name = new ArrayList();
String[] split = text.split(",");
for (String string : split) {
    if (Character.isDigit(string.trim().charAt(0))) {
        id.add(string.trim());
    } else {
        name.add(string.trim());
    }
}
```

If you want to get the 6th element,

```
System.out.println(id.get(5));
System.out.println(name.get(5));
```

output would be,

```
123457
Jack
```

Answer (score 0):

You can partition by a predicate (one that matches strings on a regex, for example):

```
String text = "132567,Amelia, 123476,Charlie, 123516,Emily, 143456,George, 123466,Harry, 123457,Jack, 125456,Joshua, 132456,Lily, 123456,Oliver";

Map<Boolean, List<String>> split = Arrays.asList(text.split(","))
        .stream().map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.matches("^\\d+$")));
```

That returns

```
{false=[Amelia, Charlie, Emily, George, Harry, Jack, Joshua, Lily, Oliver], 
true=[132567, 123476, 123516, 143456, 123466, 123457, 125456, 132456, 123456]}
```

Where `true` is the list of numbers (matching the number pattern), and `false` is the list of names (not matching the number pattern).

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume you have a list as below, you can iterate and seperate string and int items by matching with regex:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1234", "sadf", "1234124", "asdfas");

        List<String> idList = new ArrayList(); // you can make it String or Integer
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList();

        for (String item : list) {
            // here we distinguish digits only
            if (item.matches("^[0-9]*$")) {
                idList.add(item);
            }else {
                nameList.add(item);
            }
        }

        idList.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("");
        nameList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1234
1234124

sadf
asdfas
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether or not there's a particular approach you're meant to use to solve this exercise.

If you're supposed to use an array, then you need to learn how to tell if the array index number of a particular item is even or odd so you can direct the corresponding item to one of the other arrays. Look into the modulus operator.

If you're supposed to use a string, and the format of the list is exactly as you've written it, then you need to think about which characters you can use to split the list first into pairs, and then split those pairs into individual items, which you would then add to their corresponding lists.

In the unlikely event that you're supposed to use a "List", then the method for arrays above will work, but based on the complexity of the question I'm guessing Lists are coming later.